# SP2-1504: Cannot print uninitialized LOB variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to set the output of `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` to my `RET_VAR` bind variable in SQLPlus.

I tried the following `script.sql`:

```
set pagesize 0
SET LONG 9999999
VARIABLE ret_val CLOB
VARIABLE lengthRet NUMBER

select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') into :ret_val from dual;

spool testClean.sql

print :ret_val;

spool off
/ -- I had to add this line because the script would never run otherwise
```

But I get:

> SP2-1504: Cannot print uninitialized LOB variable "RET_VAL"

I also tried surrounding the assignment of `RET_VAL` with a `BEGIN`/`END` block:

```
set pagesize 0
SET LONG 9999999
VARIABLE ret_val CLOB
VARIABLE lengthRet NUMBER

BEGIN
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') into :ret_val from dual;
END;

spool testClean.sql

print :ret_val;
spool off
/
```

But then, when I try to run it in SQLPlus, I get this error:

> ERROR at line 5: ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SPOOL"

How can I assign the output of `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL` to my `RET_VAR`?

Comment: First thing that I see - you need `/` after `BEGIN ... END;` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code you posted you're trying to use the `select ... into` pattern in plain SQL, but it only works like that in a PL/SQL context. So you're right to use a block to populate a bind variable.

As @JanisBaiza said, you need a `/` after your anonymous block; but not at the end of the script:

```
set pagesize 0
SET LONG 9999999
VARIABLE ret_val CLOB

BEGIN
  select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') into :ret_val from dual;
END;
/
```

You can call the function directly though, with a `select ... from dual`:

```
BEGIN
  :ret_val := DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE');
END;
/
```

Or you could use the `execute` shorthand for a one-line anonymous block:

```
exec :ret_val := DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE');
```

It isn't obvious why you're using a bind variable for this though as you can just call the function from plain SQL (with no `into` clause!):

```
set pagesize 0
SET LONG 9999999

spool testClean.sql
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE') from dual;
spool off
```